# Get case identifier of discriminated union in pattern matching

Tags: .net, f#, functional-programming, pattern-matching, ocaml

How can I get the inferred type after `->` in pattern matching?

For example:

```
type Type =
  | Complex1
  | Complex2
  | Number of int
  | Integer of int

let calculate = function
  | Number i -> Number (i + 1)
  | Integer i -> Integer (i + 1)
  | Complex1 | Complex2 as t -> t
```

I want to shorten this function by combining `Number` and `Integer` with the or `|` pattern. How can I get the inferred case identifier to make the following function work:

```
let calculate' = function
  | Number i | Integer i ->
      // If this is Number, return Number (i + 1)
      // Else return Integer (i + 1)
  | Complex1 | Complex2 as t -> t
```

Comment: If you do `let calculate' x = match x with` rather than `let calculate' = function` then you'll be able to inspect `x` inside the match case.

Comment: @ildjarn But `x` has the type `Type`, how can I get the `Number` or `Integer` inside the match case?

Comment: My take is that, if your processes are different, you don't want to merge the cases. In one case, you return a `Number`, in the other you return an `Integer`.

Comment: @RichouHunter but the underlying processes are the same (calculate the value of `i + 1`), the difference is when I have to cast this result to `Number` or `Integer`.

Comment: You have several language tags and do not precise which one you're using. Is that willingly? It seems you want an F# answer, but could you make it clearer?

Comment: @PatJ I think F# and Ocaml handle pattern matching the same way in this case. But I'm learning F# so I'd like to have an F# answer.

Comment: @MiP The thing is, I came from the OCaml tag and started to write an edit for what I thought was "wrong syntax" (in OCaml, type identifier are lowercase) before I understood I was just in the wrong language.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If `Integer` and `Number` are semantically different, you don't *want* to merge them. That would be hard to decipher several months later and understand what you meant. Semantic difference should translate into technical difference. That is a Good Thing.

Now, if they really *are* the same, and only represented by different cases for some meta-purpose, then your data structure is wrong: it does not represent the fact that these two cases are really the same case. In order to properly represent this fact, collapse them into one case, and add a tag that would identify the kind of number:

```
type NumberKind = Integer | Other

type Type =
  | Complex1
  | Complex2
  | Number of NumberKind * int

let calculate = function
  | Number (kind, i) -> Number (kind, i + 1)
  | Complex1 | Complex2 as t -> t
```

NOTE: if you do find yourself in need to distinguish the two, you can still match on them:

```
let kind = function
  | Number (Integer, _) -> "integer"
  | Number (Other, _) -> "number"
  | Complex1 -> "complex 1"
  | Complex2 -> "complex 2"
```